# Why can't I "destroy" CRTP vector that is "self-owned" but still can deallocate its address?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stdvector, destroy, allocator

From Björn Fahller's Ligthning Talk at CPP Meeting 2023. => youtu.be/[LKKmPAQFNgE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKKmPAQFNgE) 

It's about how one can force c++ to leak memory without touching `new` or even `malloc`.

```cpp
    struct V : vector<V> {};
    auto v = V{};
    v.emplace_back();
    v.swap(v.front());  // v representation becomes uint64_t[3]{ 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
                        // so the vector allocation gets lost because no refs are left on the scope.
```

So I wonder if I can manually destroy it.

```cpp
    struct V : vector<V> {};
    auto v = V{};
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();

    auto front = v.front();

    v.swap(v.front());
    
    using allocator = std::allocator<V>;
    using atraits = std::allocator_traits<allocator>;
    auto a = front.get_allocator();
    atraits::destroy(a, &front + 1);   // Ok
    atraits::destroy(a, &front + 2);   // Ok
    atraits::destroy(a, &front + 3);   // Ok
    //  atraits::destroy(a, &front);   // error SIGSEGV
    atraits::deallocate(a, &front, 4); // still seems Ok?
```

`SIGSEGV` occurs when trying to destroy V object that owns it own address.

```cpp
0x1796320 : 0x1796320          (alloc_begin_ptr)  // It owns itself!!!
0x1796328 : 0x1796380 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x1796330 : 0x1796380   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x1796338 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x1796340 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x1796348 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x1796350 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x1796358 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x1796360 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x1796368 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x1796370 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x1796378 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)
```

So I tried moving it to stack. It seems to work fine.

```cpp
    struct V : vector<V> {};
    auto v = V{};
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();

    auto front = v.front();

    v.swap(v.front());
    
    auto v2 = std::move(front);
```

There are no objects that own itself.

```cpp
0x7ffc44d02b20 : 0x927320          (alloc_begin_ptr) // v2 on stack
0x7ffc44d02b28 : 0x927380 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x7ffc44d02b30 : 0x927380   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x927320 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x927328 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x927330 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x927338 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x927340 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x927348 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x927350 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x927358 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x927360 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)

0x927368 : 0x0          (alloc_begin_ptr)
0x927370 : 0x0 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x927378 : 0x0   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)
```

Why does `allocator_traits::destroy()` on a `vector` that owns itself trigger `SIGSEGV` ?

```cpp
    //  atraits::destroy(a, &front);   // error SIGSEGV

0x1796320 : 0x1796320          (alloc_begin_ptr)  // It owns itself!!!
0x1796328 : 0x1796380 (one_pass_content_end_ptr)
0x1796330 : 0x1796380   (one_pass_alloc_end_ptr)
```

[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMRMAPVgB3oDpkPHqSqoGBAMrIm9EAEYArKPEEAqgGdMABU4gA5AAZ9pAFYgAbKVpMGoZAFIATACFnL0lvrICecZUZ0AGFUWgBXFgYQRQAOUkCAGTwGTAA5CIAjTGIQAGYAFlIeVA1CPwYQ8MjouOLS33EklPSWLJyCz0xvBoZJAiZiAkqIqNjO7vK%2BgYImtMzsvMKNfsHh6rHl6dmWtsWASk9UMOJkdn1nXOTkcKwAagdcoIA3TB8SB%2BwHQwBBC6ubzD3R5sFgkACeHy%2BvyclwY1zCdweQSoLAIAHo0MRMPwEJCflCockCLcWExkhA9vcAOxuH63em3MKlOy3FEEEAgHjEIkPWnfBmM5nAW7LdAcl5vYi8gl0hnLYhhHy3ABqtxAtwlRClj2VH2pbipABFpfjZfSuUSIM4nKUAF6A1BUFVq/UOI23DJggiYDQORRBBh%2BgPW0givD2x0QZWUvYm35m25MMJEDVAw0qt0G425PlQgVJlPoCI8NP3RRuRSGqMAKluPAIxFjNLzAoZFokVqcTkznLd6fVPZ4fdbrYgsloqGQAH0ssBklP642g4Guy2RyPrYPhwPm%2B6IOJMAumBoNFO0BJGAQp4EFw3Y/6V92E%2BuGZuab33Tuswz9ykjyep3HSdrwYdBbyXB9lxDe5n3XCAnlQPB0FuatKUXUMX0wgV4MQ5DUJQ24IDCIkLHyKdiXw9C10wnCkJQykIEI4iJFI8j6LrBt7lcW55FuA5CIQuj8NrRiiJIsiKLQzj3B4vjQ2ol9aLwhimPEtjKOk7inDkgTcPYkTVJYiT2MXLiXFubSYzjAU%2B2sttuQ7a1sBYeswQ1V4tVucQRX6ZAAGt%2BCgrtYxzaiixczsLCeELcwTJ5%2BEwFybFOGcmH8ik7PpeLEr4NLDwyNK/Iy0K4oSpK8tS9KYuo7LypSgqqrjajdScCxWWIVRS3iqgOo7arTX5ezLWtSRw0wdAAFp8ncyUvIYHzCq8gB3BhkmFaacoINzNRIDQ5tuBBMCYHhAsg4LMtucKeEi6KLquyKetUfrBvpe7nAsR6JDMnjnoFN7Ws%2B4kZKcX6GX%2Bj7eqB7jcmemr%2BA0Jbjvg/hAYpUH6Wo9sCE7btcmzfGHgJvHCZJ4myaJinScpyCzpBpqEyxnHviob0cg1eHEeu7rIbRoK6ZKl7LuLB7IfRoWIvewHvvkMXwal4HZeFyXIe%2BmGLuopk1sTWgJxkTzCZ8sUQCAvX3h1SEBYFTWWSYBsyQIPaDdFDkTdtkhyOIe3fUeV2tQtvl82TVBE1LQH%2BGATAr19khioDhkC2Dp5tKdggjdBF5qFF9WGYc7HN3JqnC4L4vKZLovjRp4Nzst18EwTxNk7xwj4I8s2gl1XJsHw5Wnomj4I6jnXJzd4hY%2Bo23PcIDQOSweVUDBMd5IBlWZJli6J69mefQbefF64iHOoV9e7anre54Xpgl4Pr6ZLVmv6TRNFExPh2z53i%2Br8BsXH8InuJD2PuncAB%2Byox4JkxrnJmLMFiJiDhqRu6ZnYgHTpgTOT0%2BaKwlq1JOmDrp/wILgkWh9uJr3vuLPBy9iHmX5nHV6StKE32hmLAkRooT6AOLQAwigTBRCMCYVAHBuBJWxEIEQ7I%2BEHAgEgBsmBMDkEoMgUkflMDfGIMAae%2BgJqGiCAAWW%2BAAaWwFOFwagACSCRDRTgACoAE1tCfDxgAJS6AAdUIAgQ0mAMimIYGIEwaAXJ0GyAkWwwAwhMAjqYsUjhXDuFIMgJkRAWAAHlkw8GTAAMSCcwNgIACCHWvJwV4yYmAZHoKIIJ09YDjUICQKJlgKn0HqfIQoNB6A5PYFwXgAhRGkFAPoEweANA%2BPhFgMUfDyAaB0WSXoRwThnGMJM5JPBGAGEWTYOw9SBmSJqVqZpjTMDNOUG0xgrB2C6KYMopIywND8AIJwAgfSDBclQKYDyEANAIGOj6WMA1FGXMPCwZIeAWARCnFiAAjsRLE6AozYEcZIUxyTUi3FyPwRQvz4zfCYOgMCXBin9DKagz53yNBQoGJgaiJKVkaAxHgE4PThBUq%2BTStEWIfChMZUOBMpJkiCGEJiqEKwB5TloMkPyoq8AZE9tyH0HyWU%2BnJViaibJ0CYsGcMuEAJxmLKGdM5Ikg5mnAMPIDVyzVkTI2cAep/zlE7PwHssUTgDnNKsCcjpIAsQaCNT6NEh0h53IeU884PwAASXQJyhiWiQWg6AwBgBlN8Caya%2B4/CsYdW42BQJsMmSM7VJqNX6tmccY1%2BhTVLJWbw9ZoSbXuHcHsA4QyLnKO0B1N5PgC1mAUKQFIS0slNKdTLawXCeFrP4QYKxWJAQXHLeI4wkikBoCwLgWpZAKDUGyWckAzbMDXIdoGx5YgJDSFkOwJQKgJCaB0HoCZ5h5DWFCSgJRcivAeXKAEUCawojyGdYkZIcxWgLCsHUMo4gv0KGdSBno2x5g5CsK%2BnwkwVhDFCCMCD4w33iCmIMGDgG4OeGQ%2BBn9BGtj/p2EBg43qS1nFtYC4FoKWDgswFC%2Bl404UIqRSitFGLE0vPbdjLpwjBU/BxXiopCTCX0AgPkw8%2BKJOlPoNRQTfARECsTcKyOkqGASrFdKgYeA5UycKQShTlKEyqvVRwkdPax2kAETuvdtz7mPLnew0gUiUAYBwA6kg8iN3tK3V6n1tL/UTgPReqQMg5DnqPeoLQuhbPmGdValAdbXAYcQ/4CAgQiPxFArh3YwGSigYqKh6o96oPlAK0BjLPRsMoaqN%2B2rSHSPNFgw0zYqwytNc6zMMj7WLCUZ9QYKE4ah5RpjXGhNA0U2pu%2BOmwEWb0BsKs/obhNmJkCKC9RkLEbUDhdcw20gh0cULApKQPyIB8iKH4FSJQigWlUi7LkB7ABOe9nD9D5FHZtgwJhp6GFIId9zMAoCg48wEngQS10KNQIE%2BgOR1HMB4J81Ah66Cs2nhADItmMjJAGGCTtePmDEDBMkjI/HO0BLYBIZJDBaCE4mVgDIYRgBBHHBo8tWBSR2DkEz1jiGXgaMWXJ5MZxy1Ei6LZ3TMqwQhCwLZhsIKC0HCoDYdRyoDNLXNbw8tsWT3ReOaoK9CXb15AfXYVLsT0u6aqVAD1bJSAvByA2MI2mjuoHrOUDRE1RSExiW4VwThkC3Amsk3IofDSpENNgExABxfhzvuSz3gJRromGojZc/d17tf62t4e7ZVsDOeKvFeg/1gv96EN1cIyX5rWHkPVZyFX2vjXu29abwoA4Miz2rfW1W8d%2BhbicBiBYCapFbjAGQCH6TCp3eEUnbIriuQZYmEOwcE7WAcjncuzEdFr3DCKHyDCJwhhD%2BGGPx9gw33SAsGiIDgfdm/ueBAID4HcBYBIFF1qPzAx1HaFsC6EkAQFQBWipzhyhxsB6AAJSFoGANAMf0h2hxACR2OlR0eSQIR1SC3QGXiQgOh1SSkBALAImTk1UXUWfzkz6HwF4RMH1yizPVaWN3ixvUWTvQt3sDSw8Ft3gAgAd1RCdwWFd3dwOE9x6B9z9zxgD3cGD1D3D0j2j1jzUATzsyTyQh9FT1IDn18DYCsVQFCDt0o1TmSBgKAOIN1zXynW7SWk9h4BV2HTWx%2B0WQEX0GwHEyDmIGH1H3H2minxn2EL8gYiCC4NDEX2nRhFXyBzHSO03zO1Wxvzv0UAf1sxcP%2B1fyiIkQOEu3kFe34AsBiBhFyFe1H1yBhFe3eziE%2B1yCcMHzX2iJB14PB0XXwIRz80wIWGuFCQ9jdz8kaUx0oBxwmWJwJyJ3x1J3J0pzLX8ThxpwIDpwZ1s2Z1Z3Zx1k5xMG505QWXWIF18CF1s2/3F0GQvE%2B3WSlVl3ly2KB25DvymNV3Vw0E10wG10rU7XoNPQUCN0vRYMS27RS2kJtylTtz4K3Ud2dxNUMHkFNQ9y93EAkNTl00Jl03%2BPMl91Tn9y4NkLDwjy0UUPj0T2yGTw0MgDTwmCyxyzrzzwA12FL3qHKFyyLwYE7yr3T0y16FbzQ2ZNJLZNaypIWBb2mFyw7wr2pO7ysKHU%2B37xSIMC8LHwn06JZFnx6IYjCOX0iPX2OyOi30oCyJABhFuyP0MCpAsBexiAP0MFHwcISPvw22cOfwBwyPnQaM/0EQJV83XT/w0FMLgPMPAPh1tnKC9PgJIMWXaJyHlOAG6O0zwPh2yGwNyVwNDMIKDMfzILUQ0RMCoOMNoIiwN0YIixN1YJMCSw4Kt0D24MBN4P4MeTBLLQhKhNEJhIYDhPQARLxiRK4ND0kMNGRMxPkJxJjzxNUIJPUMMK0Ldx0MwD0IMM0NFBMMAO9IQM7R72sNsPsIlJqKf1cPcM8hH1lOmnDMIgCKCJCNuBVJnT2DqMyI1NO233iJMESOSN%2B1wPtPVOyNyONKNNyGNNewsEMFyCpHyHPSqI3NSIdLcw/zB14OaJjJhwgFDJACeFESnCeByNFVtm3inE4FIj6OyCx0GMWWGNJ1GJJzJwpw8l9NmPmMZ0WSWLZw507Q2N50uPwHZV2I0NIO3MOPIGOOlzOIJwuMV2uPsLVwiQeK1x11eNUFzI%2BPzO%2BLN2S0fWROsArOJLs0bI0TRGdmRKgO3luDRGSW0jRDjyWj0uwFDQ0BDzRB0XTDRBWWICBRPDwBeAmj0rCQGGiSdD0qjwHOUL0qWnQHyEMAsCpHxOIEJNHOr3fSz2CApPy2FL5KKDLzpLrwZKZPr25K6zb05Iz3qzSt60FMb3iub1FNkS7wcMlKfOHwnxYA0EQo1ByP4B0uWAXynVVIvLApiM1LiIuzyHkH3wvwKL/PPwsAP2UE%2BytKSJtNqJfzf3qIgo8yOAIHSUeXXVDLjLOCwumhqrqpQtyJaUIhcVMVSGwHareOiyYK%2BOvR%2BOdR7yQhXOOjXOs0fxcMIOWq8idE2pJFqpD12savQuaogBCBguXxBkvPnQ3y6tvMtPvOtOertPSNfIUHyH4B/Ou0MAP3kBiH/MNMUDGoMGqKms3LBvYVWycBAuf3VOd1KH8HyCAA%3D%3D%3D)]

Comment: I imagine you're deep into undefined behaviour here so it's probably not worth reasoning about it

Comment: It may be possible that the standard lacks some specification for these cases, but all of this should be specified as UB if it isn't already. You are not allowed to meddle in the internals of `std::vector` like this and the `swap` shouldn't be allowed to swap with a contained object. There is no guarantee how exactly the internal representation of `std::vector` looks or how exactly it allocates memory for its elements. The only guarantee is that it behaves _as-if_ it obtained the memory for the elements by `allocate` and constructed them by `construct`. The actual calls are not specified.

Comment: @user17732522 I guess a cyclic vector type like this is perhaps only in fiction. Besides [**_P0847_**](https://wg21.link/P0847)  provide you `c++` very own `mixin`, so you can [**_stay away from CRTP_**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/)  from `c++23` onward. `std::swap` already [**_prevent_**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)  you swap with r-value. So I guess only fictional cyclic vectors can force `std::swap` leak allocations.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming this line:

```cpp
auto front = v.front();
```

is a typo, because `v.front()` is a default constructed `V` object that you copy from. This means that that line is essentially `auto front = V{}`. You meant `auto& front = v.front()`)

`&front + 1`, `&front + 2` and `&front + 3` are pointers to empty vectors, these can be destroyed just fine.

If you attempt to destroy what `&front` points to, this is the vector with 4 elements. The last three elements are those empty vectors, which have no problem being destroyed.
But the first element of `front` is `front` itself. This is undefined behaviour because you would call the destructor on an object already being destroyed, but in practice it leads to an infinite loop because it will just call the destructor again and recursively try to destroy the same vector (and a stack overflow which leads to a segfault).

If you simply deallocate it, no destructors are called so there is no infinite loop. You might leak memory if the vector had held other vectors that allocated memory, since the destructors for those vectors wouldn't be called either.

As you've tried, the way to "fix" this is to break the "ownership" cycle, like by moving it to a new vector (`V{} = std::move(front)` / `V{}.swap(front)`).

Comment: Thank you @Artyer for correction and a good explanation. If anyone cares to pin point the corresponding UB on [eel.is](https://eel.is/c++draft/) would be great.

Comment: @sandthorn The UB is the destructor being called multiple times: for the `std::vector` base class subobject, this violates [[res.on.objects\]p2](https://wg21.link/res.on.objects#2); for non-library objects, I don't think you are allowed to call the destructor on something that isn't in life, via [[basic.life\]p(1.4)](https://wg21.link/basic.life#1.4), but I can't find an exact quote that disallows this. See: < https://godbolt.org/z/6r11777xK >). Even if double destruction isn't disallowed, the infinite loop would be UB ([[intro.progress\]](https://wg21.link/intro.progress))